# Compose - Optimize multiple backgrounds to reduce recompositions

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've created a custom modifier extension to take care of all background functions in our code. So it can handle a color background, image, and overlay (like a gradient).

I'm worried about the numerous recompositions that can happen here if all 3 are provided so seeing if anyone can think of a way to optimize this code (`thenIf` is an extension function that just checks a condition before adding the included modifier):

```
fun Modifier.background(
    pageBackground: PageBackground,
    shape: Shape = RectangleShape
): Modifier = composed {
    val backgroundColor = pageBackground.color
    val backgroundDrawableRes = pageBackground.drawableResId
    val overlay = pageBackground.overlay
    clip(shape)
        .background(backgroundColor)
        .thenIf(backgroundDrawableRes != null) {
            paint(
                painter = painterResource(backgroundDrawableRes!!),
                alignment = Alignment.Center,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )
        }.thenIf(overlay != null) {
            background(overlay!!)
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example for a scenario that you deem problematic? At first glance your code looks ok and doesn't seem to do anything more than what is necessary.

Comment: @Leviathan This absolutely does work, I'm just worried about the amount of recompositions this could trigger so I was asking if there's a "cleaner" way to accomplish the same thing

Comment: Well, it looks OK to me.